# Swift FacebookSDK login bug

Tags: swift, ios9, facebook-login

I face a strange issue using Facebook SDK to implement login.

I have 2 views :
- login view, with a facebook button
- welcome view, with access restricted to logged user

My code in login view :

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if ( FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil){
        let homePage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = homePage
    }
}

func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
    if error != nil {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
    if let _:FBSDKAccessToken = result.token {
        let homePage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = homePage
    }
}
```

In the welcome view I just put a WELCOME message on the console.

The bug is the following: when my user is not already logged, I see twice WELCOME messages.

That means that 2 threads go to welcome view: one with login button, and another with viewDidload().

What is the best way to implement the login to avoid this issue?

Thank you for your feedback.

**EDIT**

Welcome View code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (self.revealViewController() != nil) {
        self.menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        self.menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }

    print("WELCOME")
}
```

Comment: Can you post your welcome view's code?

Comment: @vivektakrani: yes, please see my edit.

Comment: What is SWRevealViewController?
Can you tell me the exact flow of your application...
Or can you share your project?

Comment: And in loginView shift the code from viewDidAppear to viewDidLoad...

Comment: @vivektakrani: shift the code from viewDidAppear to viewDidLoad effectively corrects the bug. Logic... Thank you!